# gl_FragCoord.x, y, z being 1 for all pixels and w being the depth

Tags: glsl, three.js, webgl, shader, zbuffer

I'm using THREE.js with shader. I'm trying to get the zbuffer information.

Vertex shader:

```
// switch on high precision floats
#ifdef GL_ES
precision highp float;
#endif

void main()
{
    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0);
}
```

Fragment shader:

```
#ifdef GL_ES
precision highp float;
#endif

void main()
{
    gl_FragColor = vec4(gl_FragCoord.x, gl_FragCoord.y, gl_FragCoord.z, 1.0);
}
```

There are objects with different position in the scene, thus the values in zbuffer should vary.

It's strange that `gl_FragCoord.x`, `gl_FragCoord.y` and `gl_FragCoord.z` seems to be `1.0` for all fragments, while `gl_FragCoord.w` seems to vary for different fragments.

If I use `gl_FragCoord.w`:

```
#ifdef GL_ES
precision highp float;
#endif

void main()
{
    float zbuffer = gl_FragCoord.w * 500.0;
    gl_FragColor = vec4(zbuffer, zbuffer, zbuffer, 1.0);
}
```

It seems to be the zbuffer image:

[image]

So why would `gl_FragCoord.w` be representing depth information while `gl_FragCoord.z` is always `1.0` for all fragments?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`gl_FragCoord` is in *window space*. And [window space](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Vertex_Post-Processing#Viewport_transform) is in pixel coordinates of the window. So virtually all of your fragments are going to have values > 1.0. And since you're almost certainly not rendering to a floating-point framebuffer, your colors will be clamped to the [0, 1] range.

`gl_FragCoord.z` is probably not 1.0, but it may be close enough to it, depending on your depth range and how far the objects are from the camera. If you want to get a real idea of the depth, you need to [linearize it](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Compute_eye_space_from_window_space).

Comment: How can I get screen width and height in shader?

Comment: But why is `gl_FragCoord.w` varying for different fragments?

Comment: @Ovilia: For the same reason that the other three components do. The difference is that you don't *see it*.

Comment: Additionally, if somebody asks why `w` has the depth, in reality it has "1/z" according to the standard,  but `z` is much higher than 1, so that puts the `w` value in the 0-1 range. Far depths will give darker pixels, low depths brighter ones, and thats why the OP gets those results.